Cokriging in R: Using a fit model to predict main variable when only secondary variable is available
I am trying to use cokriging in R to predict yield in an unknown area of a field based on green chlorophyll index (GCI) scores. I have a known area of a field where yield was collected, an area of the field where no yield was collected, and GCI scores across the whole field. This can be done because GCI often correlates very nicely with yield. I am trying to use cokriging to reduce some of the variance that can come with yield predictions using vegetative indices.
To illustrate it further, I have a field boundary (outer bounding box) and a smaller area within that boundary (inner bounding box): 
Yield was collected in the area around the inner bounding box: 
In contrast, GCI values were collected across the entire field: 
Now, I need to predict the yield (primary variable) based on the GCI values (co-variable) using co-kriging. My approach was to:

Fit the variograms based on the yield outside the inner boundary (and GCI across the field),
define a grid over the inner boundary,
assign GCI scores to each grid, and
perform cokriging to predict yield.

The problem is that since I am new to cokriging, I do not know if I performed this correctly, and whether the produced pred raster can be trusted or not. Can somebody take a look at my methodology and tell me:

if I performed this prediction correctly and
if/how the methodology can be improved?

Note: In this example, yield and GCI do not correlate very well; these are different values due to confidentiality.
# Load packages
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(gstat)
library(lattice)
library(automap)


### Create shapefiles
# Field boundary (outer perimeter around the field)
field_boundary <- st_sfc(
  st_polygon(list(rbind(
    c(-93.5698254821114, 41.84760355297999),
    c(-93.56820944756736, 41.84760832004355),
    c(-93.56814270867763, 41.84573009700416),
    c(-93.56976351028521, 41.845777767639674),
    c(-93.5698254821114, 41.84760355297999) # Close the polygon (repeat the first point)
  ))),
  crs = 4326 # Coordinate reference system (e.g., WGS 84)
)

# Experiment boundary (inner boundary)
exp_boundary <- st_sfc(
  st_polygon(list(rbind(
    c(-93.5693106392478, 41.84698860178182),
    c(-93.56851453963466, 41.846998135908926),
    c(-93.56853837495242, 41.84633551407523),
    c(-93.5693201733749, 41.84629737756681),
    c(-93.5693106392478, 41.84698860178182)
  ))),
  crs = 4326
)

# Create the spatial difference shapefile to define shapefile where yield was taken
diff <- st_difference(field_boundary, exp_boundary)
plot(diff)

###### Create rasters ######

## Yield
# Define raster parameters
ncol <- 16
nrow <- 18
xmin <- -93.5698254821114
xmax <- -93.56814270867763
ymin <- 41.84573009700416
ymax <- 41.84760355297999
crs <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
values <- structure(c(2467008.13766294, 2467762.87134291, 2467796.52205405, 
                      2467582.4773796, 2467505.5605134, 2467951.98711901, 2467992.14735947, 
                      2468062.83825937, 2468218.54766223, 2468097.75155726, 2468166.61377028, 
                      2468298.95495629, 2468328.68176424, 2467768.07024006, 2468038.98179257, 
                      2468230.78482828, 2468012.82714368, 2468025.60153545, 2467380.9493966, 
                      2467875.33924189, 2467922.5686595, 2467662.81980706, 2467934.85815541, 
                      2468013.2276931, 2467952.47469564, 2467799.37007333, 2468110.57689196, 
                      2468081.51121963, 2468202.27824703, 2468288.28257607, 2468350.53824907, 
                      2468314.12398775, 2468520.68332425, 2468227.63910971, 2468089.28928622, 
                      2468104.86325326, 2467649.04901272, 2467957.91723278, 2467892.27685268, 
                      2467704.02667996, 2467922.96783245, 2468061.3904269, 2468058.75140513, 
                      2468020.11167519, 2468167.07042828, 2468208.55036128, 2468297.96673811, 
                      2468286.59156085, 2468363.34932561, 2468323.15339705, 2468274.06853251, 
                      2467598.20896223, 2468047.86102408, 2468134.79587893, 2467585.24388827, 
                      2468081.97219761, 2468127.03118664, 2468142.86519138, 2468211.26929146, 
                      2468324.25545352, 2468292.56149948, 2468293.37240441, 2468339.39309713, 
                      2468452.90169554, 2468468.82582265, 2468410.3672325, 2468409.22497538, 
                      2468409.61254597, 2468304.35129188, 2468174.07741408, 2468186.60299891, 
                      2468135.65533825, 2467842.30914116, 2468022.5661953, 2468086.34187716, 
                      2468094.29080261, 2468071.93808257, 2468187.85289083, 2468156.05898938, 
                      2468258.33237432, 2468352.156038, 2468445.89133759, 2468406.22701236, 
                      2468139.25299832, 2467911.13746351, 2468187.30274999, 2468104.26090545, 
                      2467184.75814614, 2467914.59309551, 2467981.15565611, 2467712.41015988, 
                      2468153.0582213, 2468219.42922652, 2468214.87877391, 2468175.17537373, 
                      2468267.9382835, 2468253.33030983, 2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2468058.39388414, 
                      2468134.43815958, 2468114.43651734, 2467940.22512904, 2468228.06956174, 
                      2468014.63551995, 2467738.1303961, 2468144.07372449, 2468226.62573799, 
                      2468195.80383783, 2468221.22817313, 2468356.20839919, 2468324.08395748, 
                      2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2468063.68067806, 2468061.64210937, 2467997.68565861, 
                      2468092.94599605, 2468339.90601369, 2467973.42309343, 2467284.85092797, 
                      2467902.65879557, 2468037.75235821, 2468031.17342299, 2468154.60649416, 
                      2468302.26478268, 2468323.61257861, 2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2467807.89488872, 
                      2467860.91288155, 2467812.33125887, 2467866.01376375, 2468299.56186379, 
                      2467913.92802434, 2467192.73698535, 2467691.24738893, 2467830.95193633, 
                      2467907.03665015, 2468077.58631679, 2468155.51481578, 2468172.37538597, 
                      2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2468021.62447232, 2468022.12074431, 2467982.9596942, 
                      2467680.49900188, 2468238.37931816, 2467967.77468036, 2466556.95903189, 
                      2467453.07355239, 2467783.67111041, 2467798.98999172, 2467973.32095149, 
                      2468044.24143138, 2468096.1482144, 2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2468243.3514429, 
                      2468267.51080119, 2468323.27778621, 2468175.96722379, 2468449.29768055, 
                      2468254.09274075, 2466485.36933736, 2467221.53745207, 2467398.84414892, 
                      2467077.73719787, 2467217.11976138, 2467622.77179513, 2467830.10162148, 
                      2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2468356.20839919, 2468150.8589748, 2468263.30076068, 2468396.28748095, 
                      2468105.57188663, 2468559.5665722, 2468487.55740698, 2466977.50881442, 
                      2467180.80418431, 2467037.79993192, 2466363.00047672, 2466318.05045471, 
                      2467108.46417962, 2467386.40014288, 2467636.3321039, 2467876.48421985, 
                      2468096.677632, 2468236.4200312, 2468295.97280185, 2468200.87701703, 
                      2468267.73912953, 2468338.75724407, 2467994.34426177, 2468404.67842579, 
                      2468362.01287625, 2467316.62357569, 2467332.52022916, 2467161.46308169, 
                      2466507.4337401, 2466023.10059186, 2466736.63748542, 2467236.02354011, 
                      2467596.31617418, 2467878.6837845, 2468114.7132944, 2468255.31103503, 
                      2468305.45071684, 2468362.92439679, 2468358.63967584, 2468269.07169925, 
                      2468146.04009702, 2468182.66614617, 2467942.06320583, 2467847.24252021, 
                      2467582.13020246, 2467368.32558749, 2466839.87096612, 2466217.36386527, 
                      2466474.75546707, 2467088.39698582, 2467517.87752936, 2467875.13230455, 
                      2468096.65039424, 2468212.01159278, 2468245.64801681, 2468348.89532158, 
                      2468376.76724888, 2468314.83709013, 2468311.92945644, 2468161.79839491, 
                      2467679.08065948, 2468516.84878276, 2468054.64470334, 2467813.42651352, 
                      2467425.79046662, 2466946.3716634, 2466471.47663938, 2466696.66262196, 
                      2467142.4501952, 2467557.90960679, 2467895.70664372, 2468105.57258063, 
                      2468175.53145187, 2468240.33474542, 2468340.21427317, 2468479.2900379, 
                      2468473.2097765, 2468256.09856976, 2467990.10411512, 2468687.44628869, 
                      2468295.12977662, 2468035.3551926, 2467837.53994816, 2467569.66679323, 
                      2466733.3334669, 2466466.95355385, 2466846.69605978, 2467240.12657002, 
                      2467694.02130234, 2467983.74223656, 2468086.73317589, 2468159.49912475, 
                      2468338.57305873, 2468473.10971991, 2468388.43885426, 2468191.77478186, 
                      2468162.23747476), dim = c(18L, 16L))

# Create yield raster
r <- raster(ncol = ncol, 
            nrow = nrow, 
            xmn = xmin, 
            xmx = xmax, 
            ymn = ymin, 
            ymx = ymax, 
            crs = crs)



values_vector <- as.vector(values)

# Check for mismatched dimensions
if (length(values_vector) != ncell(r)) {
  stop("Length of values does not match the number of raster cells!")
}

r[] <- values_vector
plot(r)

# Clip YLD to difference raster
diff_sf <- st_sf(geometry = diff)
diff_raster <- rasterize(diff_sf, r, field = 1)
plot(diff_raster)
extent(r) <- extent(diff_sf)
r_resample <- resample(r, diff_raster, method = "bilinear")
yld_clip <- mask(r_resample, diff_raster)
plot(yld_clip)

# Set overall extent (helpful if running in RMarkdown)
yld_res <- crop(yld_clip, diff_sf)
plot(yld_res)




## GCI raster
# Define raster parameters
ncol <- 16
nrow <- 18
xmin <- -93.5698254821114
xmax <- -93.56814270867763
ymin <- 41.84573009700416
ymax <- 41.84760355297999
crs <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
values <- structure(c(2.06470588235294, 2.10089020771513, 2.04499274310595, 
                      2.00717360114778, 1.97335203366059, 1.93224932249323, 1.79087452471483, 
                      1.85305591677503, 1.67276887871854, 1.59198355601233, 1.47476635514019, 
                      1.35060449050086, 1.35395189003436, 1.42605633802817, 1.35884353741497, 
                      1.39189189189189, 2.00717360114778, 2.00717360114778, 2.06470588235294, 2.10089020771513, 
                      2.04499274310595, 2.00717360114778, 1.97335203366059, 1.93224932249323, 
                      1.79087452471483, 1.93198992443325, 1.68614718614719, 1.50873786407767, 
                      1.48708487084871, 1.4017094017094, 1.34053156146179, 1.43106457242583, 
                      1.35139573070608, 1.35609756097561, 1.42929292929293, 1.36080586080586, 
                      2.03188405797101, 2.03862660944206, 2.01133144475921, 2.02857142857143, 
                      2.02937062937063, 1.99864314789688, 1.8125, 1.55959595959596, 
                      1.46580406654344, 1.45652173913043, 1.38095238095238, 1.31270358306189, 
                      1.3240589198036, 1.37699680511182, 1.27851851851852, 1.23953823953824, 
                      1.25637181409295, 1.31133671742809, 1.91492329149233, 1.9901269393512, 
                      1.86369770580297, 1.90835579514825, 1.83622828784119, 1.65842696629213, 
                      1.62699256110521, 1.29365079365079, 1.26666666666667, 1.34838709677419, 
                      1.25150602409639, 1.21067821067821, 1.16358463726885, 1.14058355437666, 
                      1.15496688741722, 1.21143617021277, 1.26300984528833, 1.28831562974203, 
                      1.95966620305981, 2, 1.88507265521797, 1.82338308457711, 1.57991803278689, 
                      1.36814159292035, 1.37732656514382, 1.17366946778711, 1.14442916093535, 
                      1.21045197740113, 1.13297150610583, 1.10775295663601, 1.0681233933162, 
                      1.11607142857143, 1.1188986232791, 1.13316892725031, 1.19102564102564, 
                      1.19022457067371, 1.92119565217391, 1.88085676037483, 1.85971685971686, 
                      1.68571428571429, 1.35972461273666, 1.25078864353312, 1.25075987841945, 
                      1.22099447513812, 1.10539845758355, 1.04260651629073, 1.06337135614702, 
                      1.08132147395172, 1.06423173803526, 1.15473145780051, 1.07363420427553, 
                      1.040369088812, 1.08984830805134, 1.10962241169306, 1.89124668435013, 
                      1.89093298291721, 1.71752085816448, 1.47876447876448, 1.30914826498423, 
                      1.25854383358098, 1.20494186046512, 1.17631224764468, 1.07865168539326, 
                      1.03393939393939, 1.02912621359223, 1.03321033210332, 1.0359355638166, 
                      1.1318407960199, 1.05807200929152, 1.03258426966292, 1.05756207674944, 
                      1.06728538283063, 1.81115335868188, 1.84644194756554, 1.62708333333333, 
                      1.33447098976109, 1.24283559577677, 1.16643356643357, 1.1673640167364, 
                      1.13154362416107, 1.14117647058824, 1.0897597977244, 1.03694581280788, 
                      1.03667481662592, 1.0359355638166, 1.1318407960199, 1.05807200929152, 
                      1.03258426966292, 1.05756207674944, 1.06728538283063, 1.81115335868188, 
                      1.84644194756554, 1.62708333333333, 1.33447098976109, 1.24283559577677, 
                      1.16643356643357, 1.1673640167364, 1.13154362416107, 1.14117647058824, 
                      1.0897597977244, 1.03694581280788, 1.03667481662592, 0.988179669030733, 
                      1.0832328106152, 1.05523590333717, 1.03318584070796, 1.03314917127072, 
                      1.07885714285714, 1.85069008782936, 1.80373831775701, 1.47636363636364, 
                      1.22595419847328, 1.17285714285714, 1.17066290550071, 1.20487106017192, 
                      1.12820512820513, 1.11835106382979, 1.13066666666667, 1.07388535031847, 
                      1.03654080389769, 1.00819672131148, 1.04225352112676, 1.0281214848144, 
                      1.00869565217391, 0.975427350427351, 0.967741935483871, 1.83709273182957, 
                      1.66171792152704, 1.30555555555556, 1.24191063174114, 1.25229357798165, 
                      1.25621118012422, 1.27315541601256, 1.1813110181311, 1.16462585034014, 
                      1.14171122994652, 1.09677419354839, 1.06905055487053, 1.07125603864734, 
                      1.03596287703016, 1.01327433628319, 0.977659574468085, 0.906639004149378, 
                      0.904862579281184, 1.83668341708543, 1.68076109936575, 1.335, 
                      1.29276315789474, 1.29450915141431, 1.30267558528428, 1.31208053691275, 
                      1.29085457271364, 1.19178082191781, 1.12516469038208, 1.09768637532134, 
                      1.12797992471769, 1.0985401459854, 1.03567318757192, 0.983498349834983, 
                      0.956066945606695, 0.835892514395393, 0.774904214559387, 1.83353584447145, 
                      1.59531090723751, 1.41058394160584, 1.35599284436494, 1.33506944444444, 
                      1.32943143812709, 1.27858293075684, 1.27162367223065, 1.21805555555556, 
                      1.17686170212766, 1.10266159695817, 1.09864364981504, 1.09638554216867, 
                      1.04701834862385, 0.947141316073355, 0.907975460122699, 0.761425959780622, 
                      0.696113074204947, 1.82309582309582, 1.70707070707071, 1.54305977710233, 
                      1.47665369649805, 1.44606946983547, 1.35255354200988, 1.27328244274809, 
                      1.22549019607843, 1.18255033557047, 1.16120576671035, 1.07221542227662, 
                      0.977298524404086, 0.932461873638344, 0.951560818083961, 0.908045977011494, 
                      0.845624385447394, 0.778492647058824, 0.715547703180212, 1.81173594132029, 
                      1.82224909310762, 1.6557734204793, 1.46382189239332, 1.40978077571669, 
                      1.24740740740741, 1.09138381201044, 1.09171974522293, 1.09355246523388, 
                      1.08148148148148, 1.01841196777906, 0.910714285714286, 0.808447937131631, 
                      0.815354713313897, 0.803030303030303, 0.76076993583868, 0.748438893844781, 
                      0.715547703180212, 1.81173594132029, 1.82224909310762, 1.6557734204793, 
                      1.46382189239332, 1.40978077571669, 1.24740740740741, 1.09138381201044, 
                      1.09171974522293, 1.09355246523388, 1.08148148148148, 1.01841196777906, 
                      0.910714285714286, 0.808447937131631, 0.815354713313897, 0.803030303030303, 
                      0.76076993583868, 0.748438893844781, 0.692504258943782), dim = c(18L, 
                                                                                       16L))

gci <- raster(ncol = ncol, 
              nrow = nrow, 
              xmn = xmin, 
              xmx = xmax, 
              ymn = ymin, 
              ymx = ymax, 
              crs = crs)

# Flatten the values matrix into a vector
values_vector <- as.vector(values)

# Assign values to the raster
gci[] <- values_vector

# Plot the raster
plot(gci)

# Clip GCI to difference raster
field_boundary_sf <- st_sf(geometry = field_boundary)
field_boundary_raster <- rasterize(field_boundary_sf, gci, field = 1)
plot(field_boundary_raster)
extent(gci) <- extent(field_boundary_sf)
gci_resample <- resample(gci, field_boundary_raster, method = "bilinear")
gci_clip <- mask(gci_resample, field_boundary_raster)
plot(gci_clip)

# Set overall extent
gci_res <- crop(gci_clip, field_boundary_sf)
plot(gci_res)

# Ensure that extents match
extent(gci_res) <- extent(yld_res)

# Resample Yield raster so that resolutions are equal
yld_res_resample <- resample(yld_res, gci_res, method = "bilinear")
plot(yld_res_resample)



###### Cokriging ######
### Preparing the data
# Convert rasters to points
yield <- rasterToPoints(yld_res_resample, spatial = TRUE)
gci <- rasterToPoints(gci_res, spatial = TRUE)

# Since the row numbers may not be equal, converting to dataframes and combining the common rows
yield_df <- as.data.frame(yield)
gci_df <- as.data.frame(gci)

# Renaming rows
colnames(yield_df)[1] <- "yield"
colnames(gci_df)[1] <- "gci"

# Combining data
combined_data <- merge(yield_df, gci_df, by = c("x","y"), all = FALSE)

# Convert back to a sp dataframe
coordinates(combined_data) <- ~x + y

# Ensure CRS match
proj4string(combined_data) <- proj4string(yld_res_resample)



## Fitting variograms
# Initialize the gstat object for co-kriging
g_co <- gstat(NULL, id = "yield", formula = yield ~ 1, data = combined_data)
g_co <- gstat(g_co, id = "gci", formula = gci ~ 1, data = combined_data)

### Define variograms with Automap (convenient to plot data to plot the variogram)
### (Note: Using automap to obtain nugget, psill, and range to better fit variograms)
yield_var <- autofitVariogram(yield~1, combined_data, model = c("Sph"))
plot(yield_var)

gci_var <- autofitVariogram(gci~1, combined_data, model = c("Sph"))
plot(gci_var)

# Define the same variograms with gstat (necessary to run the code)
yield_var <- gstat::variogram(yield ~ 1, combined_data)
gci_var <- gstat::variogram(gci ~ 1, combined_data)

### gstat: Fitting the variograms
# Fit variograms
yield_mod = gstat::fit.variogram(object = yield_var, 
                                 model = gstat::vgm(psill = 199456,
                                                    nugget = 0,
                                                    range = 0.06,
                                                    model = "Sph"))


gci_mod = gstat::fit.variogram(object = gci_var, 
                               model = gstat::vgm(psill = 11,
                                                  nugget = 0,
                                                  range = 0.05,
                                                  model = "Sph"))


### Modeling the co-variable (better correlations usually seen, but this will suffice for the given example)
lattice::xyplot(gci ~ yield, data = combined_data@data, pch=20, cex=1.2)
with(combined_data@data, cor(yield, gci)) # Same as the correlation matrix modeled earlier

plot(gci_var, pl=T, model=gci_mod)

yield_mod$range[2] # target variable
gci_mod$range[2] # co-variable

round(gci_mod$psill[1]/sum(gci_mod$psill), 2)
round(yield_mod$psill[1]/sum(yield_mod$psill), 2)

g <- gstat(NULL, id = "yield", form = yield ~ 1, data = combined_data) # Primary variable
g <- gstat(g, id = "gci", form = gci ~ 1, data = combined_data) # Co-variable

v_cross <- variogram(g)
str(v_cross)
plot(v_cross, pl=T)


## Fitting cross-variogram
g <- gstat(g, id = "yield", model = yield_mod, fill.all=T)

g <- fit.lmc(v_cross, g, fit.method=6, correct.diagonal=1.01)
plot(variogram(g), model=g$model)


## Checking parameters
str(gci_mod) # see where the parameters are stored

str(g$data, max.level=1)
str(g$model, max.level=1)

str(g$model$yield, max.level = 1)

# Comparing the models: Co-variable
g$model$gci$psill - gci_mod$psill
sum(g$model$gci$psill) - sum(gci_mod$psill)
sum(g$model$gci$psill)

# Comparing the models: Primary
g$model$yield$psill - yield_mod$psill
sum(g$model$yield$psill) - sum(yield_mod$psill)
sum(g$model$yield$psill)




# Extract the bounding box for experiment boundary
bbox <- st_bbox(exp_boundary)
extent_area <- extent(bbox["xmin"], bbox["xmax"], bbox["ymin"], bbox["ymax"])

# Define grid over the experimental area
extent_area <- as(extent_area, "SpatialPolygons")

# Create a regular grid matching the GCI raster resolution
grd <- spsample(extent_area, type = "regular", cellsize = res(gci_res))
gridded(grd) <- TRUE
proj4string(grd) <- proj4string(gci_res)  # Ensure CRS matches


# Convert grid to SpatialPoints for extraction
grd_points <- as(grd, "SpatialPoints")

# Extract mean GCI values from the raster
gci_values <- raster::extract(gci_res, grd_points, fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE)


# Attach extracted GCI values to the grid
grd <- SpatialPixelsDataFrame(grd, data = data.frame(mean_gci = gci_values))
#plot(grd)

### Co-kriging
pred <- predict(g, grd)
plot(pred)

